# Не могу установить модули на python

Tags: python-3.x

*Только что установил Python 3.7.7.* Пишу в строке `pip install colorama`, мне выбивает ошибку.

```
>>> pip install colorama
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install colorama
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Это надо писать в командной строке, а не в интерпретаторе питона.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> pip install colorama
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install colorama
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Вы пытаетесь написать команду установки модуля находясь при этом в интерпретаторе Python. Обратите внимание на приглашение `>>>` - это сигнал к тому, что вы находитесь в интерпретаторе.

Выходите из него и устанавливайте пакет, находясь в консоли.

Answer (score 0):

Установка модулей производится в командной строке (а не в самом Python'e) данной коммандой: `pip install имя_модуля`. В вашем случае будет `pip install colorama`. Так же предварительно должен быть установлен сам pip - `sudo apt install python-pip` (Для Linux) [Для Winsows (клик)](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/)

Подключение модуля в коде - `import имя_модуля`, в вашем случае - `import colorama`